# Sitemap.xml hidden from visitors

Tags: xml, sitemap, robots.txt, sitemap.xml

I wish to have my sitemap.xml not visible to users. Currently, the sitemap index and sitemaps are at the root of the site and i included it in the robots.txt.

As we are starting to play with it and tweak it with cool stuff that no one else in our business field is doing, we wish to hide it.

I could always name my sitemapindex and sitemaps with weird names and still put them at the root of the site, submit it myself manually thru Google Webmaster tool and the the robots.txt so it doesn't point on it.

But even there, someone lucky enought or smart enought could find it.

I want to know if there is a way to submit a site map that is not uploaded on our site.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this? The XML sitemap is normally a list of pages that you want the public to be able to find easily. Why would you need to hide this information?

Comment: We have a siteplan set up for that, make user experience easier. Our sitemap.xml is a list of our URLs the we want Google to crawl. We want to hide it so our competitors do not see how we tweak it. We have a multilanguage site, there are tweaks to be done to prevent a huge amount of 404s.

Comment: 404 won't hurt you if they are real 'gone' pages. If you have broken links, then twisting your sitemap won't solve that issue. Only removing broken links will, or set a nofollow on pages having broken links.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not really possible, although you could post your sitemap on another "secret" website with links to your website. It would make it harder to find.

But if you want to hide the stuff you are working on, just don't put it in your sitemap in the first place (and make sure there is no link to it on your site). Or if you don't want it ranked yet, set `noindex,nofollow` tags on your work-in-progress pages. Remove these tags when ready.